# How to add short video file between 2 viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller

I would like to perform custom viewcontroller effect, but it seems too difficult with only coding.
is there anyway I could add a very short video between 2 viewcontroller?
or is there any way can archive the same effect?

Thanks

Comment: If you think coding a custom transition is difficult, the solution you're purposing is much more difficult and definitely frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could present the second viewController without animation and upon the secondviewcontroller's `viewDidLoad` you can make an animation using an `UIImageView`that is on the full screen of the controller.